# Zend Framework Rewrite does not work for some URLs under IIS7

Tags: zend-framework, iis-7, url-rewriting

I recently moved a web site written based on Zend framework 1 from Apache to IIS7. I followed the instructions by Rob Allen http://akrabat.com/winphp-challenge/zend-framework-url-rewriting-in-iis7/ to import the rules into IIS.

Everything works fine except URL with this format:

www.example.com/products/download/productname-4.0.0.zip

It shows the IIS 404 error page, not the customized 404 page in the application. I suspect that it is IIS7 configuration issue.

Anyone has the similar experience here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a web.config that I use in IIS7 for Zend Framework

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```